# Spring 2.5 in EJB container

Tags: java, spring, dependencies, ejb-3.0, java-ee-5

I would like to use the spring framework within an EJB3 project. In detail I would like to use the JDBC template class which should be instantinated from a given data source. When I put the spring.jar to my Jboss lib directoy everything is working fine. But when I put the JAR inside my EAR only there seems to be external dependencies from JDbcTemplate to other libraries. EARs/EJBs classloader try to instantinate the JdbcTemplate and shows me that he can not load the class because of external dependencies. It does not show me which additional JARs I have to put in.

Question: Does some body know which addtional JARs I have to include or even how I can search for depending JARs with external tool. I remember there is a tool which can do this, but I do not know its name anymore. I think something like jarjar etc.

Could anyone help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This smells like an EAR config problem not an Spring problem. Are you sure that the jar is in the EJB's classpath? You might want to check the MANIFEST.MF file of the EJB's jar to verify this.